# How do I remove everything except price?

Tags: regex, sublimetext2, notepad++

I have a messy list and I'm trying to get rid of everything except prices, which do have a dollar sign $ in front.

They don't have the same number of digits, though. Some are "$X.XX" and others are "$XX.XX"

And if possible, I'd like to be able to insert a "+" in between the prices, so it'll look something like "$X.XX+$XX.XX+..."

I tried searching, but the solutions didn't work for me (they used the pound symbol though, which might have needed a different query)

Comment: Could you give us an example of the full lines in the list. Basically, what is that you try to remove.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this (should work with notepad++):

```
search: (?>[^$]+|\$(?!\d{1,2}\.\d{2}))*(\$\d{1,2}\.\d{2})
replace: $1+
```

(or `search: .*?(\$\d{1,2}\.\d{2})` )

and you remove by hand the last +

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match your prices would be

```
\$\d+\.\d+
```

where `\$` is a dollar sign (remember you need to escape it because just `$` means end of string, `\d+` means at least one digit, `\.` a dot (again, escape because `.` means any character)

This will match to 
`$1.2`, `$24.67` etc.

In Sublime Text, you could then remove everything else by using `Find-Replace`:

find: `.*(\$\d*\.\d*).*`

replace: `$1`

**Example**

```
product1 $14.22 categoryA
product2 $5.2 categoryA
product3 $0.2456 categoryB
```

would become

```
$14.22
$5.2
$0.2456
```